# Java Gson Deserialization of selected fields from a list inside an object

Tags: java, gson, flickr, android

I'm trying to figure out a way to selectively de-serialize specific fields from flickr.

```
{"photos":{"page":1,"pages":10,"perpage":100,"total":1000,"photo":[{"id":"","owner":"","secret":"","server":"","farm":,"title":"","ispublic":,"isfriend":,"isfamily":0,"url_s":"","height_s":"","width_s":""},...]}
```

I receive an object that contains two lists (photos and photo) and i would like to model in Java only the id, url_s and title from photo.

I figured out that I can create my java module with @expose annotation for the fields i'm interested in and than use 
        builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation(); 
this way I'll control which fields get deserialized from photo (still not sure it's gonne work that way), but what about photos?

My questions are:

1. **Is there a way to ignore that list? do I have to model a Java class that contains two lists (with their respective fields) just to grab what I need from the second list?**
2. expanding upon the former question, if my module class for photo is:

   ```
   public class GalleryItem {
   @Expose()
   private String mCaption;
   @Expose()
   private String mId;
   @Expose()
   private String mUrl;
   }
   ```

   **can i call gson only on the part i need?**

   ```
   Type galleryListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<GalleryItems>> (){}.getType();

   List<GalleryItems> itemsList = gson.fromJson(jsonString, galleryListType);
   ```
3. **can I somehow use setExclusionStrategies to skip the Photos list?**

   ```
   gsonBuilder.setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {  
   @Override
   public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
       **return f.getName().contains("photos")**;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> incomingClass) {
       return ;
   }
   });
   ```

I've already implemented a solution using raw JSONObject/JSONArray but I'm curious regarding using GSON for the task at hand.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Gson provides deserialisation on Java fields. If you mark as a `transient` your variable, Gson will not serialised to JSON. Gson also provides finer deserialisation control via annotations: `@Expose(deserialize = false/true)` 
The last option would be writing your custom `JsonDeserializer<T>`

Comment: i am aware you can use @Expose (as i wrote above) and transient wont help me because I'm trying to deserialize selectively and not serialize everything except the transient variable